# Java - Database URL within the DAL project

Tags: java, database, dao, modularity

I am rewriting a back-end code of an API. It was using Glassfish to store the database URL, username, password, ...

I would like to use a better solution so that we can easily change our web server and database without modifying the code.

My idea was to store the database information (url,username,..) inside the `web.xml` and retrieve them inside a `baseDAO`.

Here is my project structure

- RestAPIProject
- BusinessProject
- DALProject
- DTOProject

Inside my DALProject I would create this class

```
public class BaseDAO {

    public Connection getConnection() {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB";
        String name = "root";
        String password = "";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, password);
        return con;
    }
}

public class UserDAO extends BaseDAO {

    public User getAll() {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I store those database's information ? What is the best practice to make it modular ? I need to easily change the database whenever I have to.

Comment: You can use JNDI datasource on the server, that the standard in Java EE. But what server do you use ?

Comment: For the moment, it is a PostgreSQL database but It mays change to Oracle

Comment: I speak about application server, with Glassfish you can use JNDI datasource.

Comment: Oh ok sorry, We are using Glassfish yes. It is the most comon way to store database inside glassfish ? Could you show an example of how to retrieve those data ? I know how to create it

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque And what is the difference with JDBC ressources ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to store it in the `application.properties` file and change it when you need:

```
# Details for datasource
application.db.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
application.db.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB
application.db.username = root
application.db.password =
```

Then you can use it in your configuration bean:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class DataConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("application.db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("application.db.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("application.db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("application.db.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```